# When I subscribe to Subject, Unable to get the value in angular 8

Tags: angular, rxjs

I Have 1stcomponent, I am sending data to Service  and in Service I am using Subject to emit the Data.
In 2ndComponent I Subscribed to the Subject. But I am unable to get the data in 2nd component which I
Subscribed.

**component One**

```
editUser(user){
   this.dashboardService.editUser(user);
   this.router.navigate(['/form']);
}
```

**Service.ts**

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
mySubject= new Subject<any>();
formData = this.mySubject.asObservable();

editUser(user){
   this.mySubject.next(user);
}
```

**component-two**

```
ngOnInit(){
   this.dashboardService.formData.subscribe(userData =>{
        console.log(userData);
   })
}
```

Comment: hello @sunddep checkout my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The route change makes it seem like you are subscribing after pushing the data to the Subject. A Subject will only emit to current subscribers and won't hold the value. If this is the case then use a BehaviourSubject or ReplaySubject instead.

Answer (score 0):

try to update it like this

```
userDataStatusChange: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();

editUser(user){
      this.userDataStatusChange.next(user);
    }
```

And in component 2

```
ngOnInit(){
     this.dashboardService.userDataStatusChange.subscribe((userData) =>{
               console.log(userData);
        })
    }
```

Comment: put a breakpoint and check if  editUser(user) is getting called, also you have 2 methods with the same name

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using formData at all, just replace with the below code and you should be fine.

I've put up a short demo using your code and have just used one component for example. :)

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-etcned?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts

```html
ngOnInit(){
      this.dashboardService.mySubject.subscribe(userData =>{
               alert(userData);
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**working demo** in this [StackBlitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jpfqyo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcomponent-two%2Fcomponent-two.component.html)

### EDIT

---

Subject is not emitted latest value to subscribers. thus when route changed it will not getting value from previous component. You need Two ways here..

1. Use `BehaviorSubject` instead of `subject`.
2. Use one reference variable. use `startWith()` rxjs operator.

I am going to second approach, because of you already using `Subject`. edited code is available in below...

**Just use `async pipe`**, in component Two. Because of `async-pipe` is handling subscribing and unsubscribing part of subject observable and we do not have to thought about it any-more.

**component.one.html**

```
<h4> Component : 1 </h4>
<button (click)="sendData()">sendData </button>
<hr>
```

**component.one.ts**

```
export class ComponentOneComponent  {
   mySubject = this.communicateService.getSubjectObservable();
   constructor(private communicateService: CommunicateService) { }
   sendData(){
      this.communicateService.editUser({name: 'wesbos'});
      this.router.navigate(['/form']);
   } 
}
```

**component.two.html**

```
<h4> Component : 2 </h4>

<div *ngIf="data | async as user">
  {{user | json}}
</div>
```

In above, we use `async-pipe` to subscribing data automatically..

**component.two.ts**

```
export class ComponentTwoComponent {
   data = this.communicationService.getSubjectObservable();
   constructor(private communicationService: CommunicateService) { }
}
```

**communicate-service.ts**

```
export class CommunicateService {
  latestData = {};

  mySubject: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();
  formData = this.mySubject.asObservable();

  editUser(user){
     this.latestData = {...user};
     this.mySubject.next(user);
  }
  getSubjectObservable(){
     return this.formData.pipe(startWith(this.latestData));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to make a variable like this

```
mySubject= new Subject<any>();
```

after that in component you have to call `edituser()` method with service

```
 editUser(data: any){
    this.mySubject.next(data);
 }
```

and for get the edituser detail you need to call `geteditUser()` under `constructor()` or `ngOnInit()`

```
geteditUser(): Observable<any> {
    return this.mySubject.asObservable();
}
```

after that you need to call like this

Eg

```
this.yourservicename.geteditUser().subscribe(res=>{
  console.log('res ==> ', res); // your response
});
```